# Access to Path for Documents Folder denied when creating text document

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to make a text file in my documents

```cs
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);
    sw.WriteLine("Hello!");
}
```

It says that path is denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an access denied error because `File.CreateText()` expects a full path to the file that should be created. The code is giving it the path to your Documents folder. Since that path already exists and is a folder, that is the cause of the access denied error.

You should change `path` to point to a non-existent text file first. Also, `StreamWriter.Dispose()` needs to be called in order to close the file (this is typically done with a `using` statement).

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    path = Path.Combine(path, "MyFile.txt");
    using(StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not given the path to the file you are trying to create; only the folder itself. Instead you could do something like

```cs
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path + $"\hello.txt")) 
    sw.WriteLine("Hello!");
```